# Check in between dates - Laravel SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

I find myself writing here, I can't figure out how I can accomplish the following query.
I have a booking table which is formed like this:

```
id - arrival_date - departure_date - nroom
1 - '2021-10-10' - '2021-10-25' - 5
2 - '2021-10-26' - '2021-10-28' - 6
```

Now if I select a date that goes between 2021-10-11 and 2021-10-20 and select room 5, how can I go about saying that it is already occupied?

I tried with

```
$check=Hotel::where(function ($query) use($value) {
               $query->where('nroom',$value->id);
                    })
              ->where(function ($wh) use ($arrival_date, $departure_date) {
                $wh->whereBetween('arrival_date', [$arrival_date, $departure_date])
                ->oRwhereBetween('departure_date', [$arrival_date, $departure_date]);
                })
                ->first();
```

In this way the intermediate dates are not calculated….
You can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a booking table and add every reservation there, then you need to pull the data with the relationship.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).